# Map bluetooth device to a serial port in Linux

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth, serial-port, rfcomm, smslib

I have connected my mobile phone to my laptop via bluetooth. Now I need to map that bluetooth connection to a virtual serial port. Purpose of doing that is to configure [SMSLib](http://smslib.org) Java library to send sms via my phone. Ubuntu 12.04 is the OS running in my laptop. I have executed following command and gave "/dev/rfcomm0" as my serial port to the SMSLib application parameter.

```
rfcomm bind /dev/rfcomm0 <bdaddr> <rfchan>
```

But it gave me an run time error by saying port couldn't identify. How do i overcome from this issue?

Have a great day!

Comment: Installed bluez? I don't have anything really working, but am facing a problem with connections to yours.

Comment: hey esej, i have switched to windows and its working charm. So i didnt try it out in ubuntu. I'll update this question if i try it out again in ubuntu.

Comment: Which bdaddr are you using? You will have to you use your local MAC address.